# A uniform convergence argument in Evans's Partial Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u:{\bf R}^n\to{\bf R}$ is some continuous function and $\{u_j\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on ${\bf R}^n$ such that
$$
u_j\to u\quad\text{locally uniformly in }{\bf R}^n\ \text{as }j\to\infty
\tag{1}
$$
Suppose $u$ has a strict local maximum at some point $x_0\in{\bf R}^n$, i.e., 
$$
u(x)<u(x_0)\tag{2}
$$
for all points $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$ with $x\neq x_0$. By (2), for each (fixed) sufficiently small $R>0$, we have
$$
\max_{\partial B_R} u < u(x_0) \tag{3}
$$
where $B_R$ is the closed ball of radius $R$ centered at $x_0$.
In view of (1), there exists some postive integer $N(R)$ (may depend on $R$) such that
$$
\max_{\partial B_R} u_j < u_j(x_0)\quad\text{for all } j>N(R)\tag{4}
$$
Consequently, $u_j$ (with $j>N(R)$) attains a local maximum at some point in the interior of $B_R$.

> If we replace $R$ by sequence of radii tending to zero, we can conclude that
>    **for each sufficiently large** $j,$ there exists a point $x_j$ at which $u_j$ has a local maximum and $x_j\to x_0$ as $j\to\infty$.

---

The argument above is tailored and paraphrased from a long introduction of viscosity solution of Hamilton-Jacobi equations in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations* (Chapter 10.1).

---

**Question**: Would anyone elaborate the very last sentence in the argument above?

---

I can only see the following is true:

> if we replace $R$ by sequence of radii tending to zero, we can conclude that there exists a *subsequence* $u_{j_m}$ with the property that $u_{j_m}$ has a local maximum at some $x_{j_m}$ and $x_{j_m}\to x_0$ as $m\to\infty$.

---

Here is the original argument in Evans's book:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: @Sergio Andrade: Thanks for editing the tag. While my question grows out of a PDE book I'm reading, IMO the question *per se* is not about PDE. But I think it does not harm to leave the tag here. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtaining $x_j$ for all sufficiently large $j$'s and not only for a subsequence is not harder. Let me summarize: for every $R>0$ there is $N(R)$ such that for each $j \ge N(R)$, $u_j$ attains a local maximum at some point in the interior of $B_R$.

Now for a fixed sequence $R_k \to 0$, we can assume that the corresponding sequence $N(R_k)$ is increasing. For each $k$ and $N(R_k) \le j < N(R_{k+1})$, $u_j$ attains a local maximum at some point $x_j$ in the interior of $B_{R_k}$. It is evident that $x_j \to x_0$.

Comment: I assume that "for all $j$'s" means "for all sufficiently large $j$'s" in this answer. (But it does not really matter eventually.) It seems that I overthinked something unnecessary about the sequence $N(R_k)$. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Good point, I edited the answer accordingly.